# Use WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder without Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing, .net-7.0

For my .NET 7 Web application (MVC) I want to create an in memory webserver listening on a specified url which I can then point my Selenium browser driver to to execute my browser tests.

I'm trying to use the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` to build an `IWebHost` and then start it but the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` wants a `Startup.cs`:

> No application configured. Please specify startup via
> IWebHostBuilder.UseStartup, IWebHostBuilder.Configure, injecting
> IStartup or specifying the startup assembly via StartupAssemblyKey in
> the web host configuration.

Sadly I don't have a `Startup.cs` since everything is happening at top level in my `Program.cs`.

I sure could convert back to the old approach using a `Startup.cs` but that surely cannot be the correct approach. Can anybody shed some light for me here and/or provide a working excample? Thanks in advance ;)

*** UPDATE ***

[Guru Strons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76075477/16440) suggested my approach to hosting is a bit outdated so I tried this:

In my web application I now have a `Program.cs` which looks like this (a lot of code removed for brevity):

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunServer(args);
    }

    public static void RunServer(string[] args, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.WebHost.UseUrls(/* some url */);

        //  a lot more of configuring services...
        
        var app = builder.Build();
        
        //  and a lot of configuring the pipeline...
        
        if(cancellationToken == null)
        {
            app.Run();
        }
        else
        {
            app.RunAsync(cancellationToken.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Since `app.Run()` would block the thread I thought I might do this trick with the `CancellationToken`. So in my test project I now try to spin up a test server like this:

```
var cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
MyNamespace.Program.RunServer(Array.Empty<string>(), cancelTokenSource.Token);
```

I store the cancelTokenSource for later to stop the webserver when the tests are done. Eventhough the server runs just fine by itself (when running its own web project) I can't seem to get it working in the test project. Whenever I point my browser to it I get a 404.

Comment: I have a sample app here, that demonstrates how to self-host a web app using top-level programs and minimal hosting with tools like Selenium and Playwright: https://github.com/martincostello/dotnet-minimal-api-integration-testing

Answer (score 0):

`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` is quite dated approach - [`HostBuilder` replaced `WebHostBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#hostbuilder-replaces-webhostbuilder) in default templates in ASP.NET Core 3.0 (though it can be used).

ASP.NET Core 6.0 went further and introduced the new [minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model) which allows to create a simple app just like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

> since everything is happening at top level in my Program.cs.

You still can use [the generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) with [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) if you want, but most of scenarios can be covered with new minimal one.

So in the nutshell - just create a new ASP.NET Core app from the default template (either using IDE or [`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) CLI command) and that's all.

See also:

- [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 5.0 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [Code samples migrated to the new minimal hosting model in ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [ASP.NET Core tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the minimal hosting model. I have applied it but still can't start an in memory webserver. What I did is not use top level statements but wrap all the statements in your code into a static method  `RunServer` inside a`class Programm` I created. To avoid blocking the main thread I chose `app.RunAsync()` instead of your version. When I use this code to spin up a test server and point my browser to it I get a 404. Surely I'm still misssing something. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Mats without seeing full environment and code - I'm afraid not.

Comment: Will update my question.